# How to find a multiline pattern and add new line using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am new to using 'sed'. I have a file which has some text as follows.

```
this is a test1
length 12
width 12

this is test2
length 50
width 50
```

I am not sure how multiline sed command would look like. I want to my output to be

```
this is a test1
length 12
//width 12
new width 40

this is test2
length 50
width 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sed` command. I hope this will help you,

```
sed ':loop ; N  ; /\n$/{s/.*/\/\/&new width 40\n/} ; t loop' FileName.txt
```

**Output:**

```
this is a test1
length 12
//width 12
new width 40

this is test2
length 50
width 50
```

Answer (score 0):

This command would do this for you.

```
sed 's:\(width 12\)://\1\nnew width 40:g'

o@o:~$ sed 's:\(width 12\)://\1\nnew width 40:g' se.file 
this is a test1
length 12
//width 12
new width 40

this is test2
length 50
width 50
```